# Change a div with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need a small script that is loaded when the website is loaded, and modify all  that had not define "date-mode", and place = "date-mode=none", Somting like this:

```
<body>
  <div date-mode="page"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div id="select"></div>
</body>
```

and the result is:

```
<body>
   <div date-mode="page"></div>
   <div date-mode="none"></div>
   <div id="select" date-mode="none"></div>
</body>
```

Someone can help me? Thank you!

Comment: post what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out.

```
window.onload = function () {
    var divs = document.body.getElementsByTagName('div'), div, i;
    for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i += 1) {
        div = divs[i];
        if ( !div.getAttribute('date-mode') ) {
            div.setAttribute('date-mode', 'none');
        }
    }
};
```